# Access violation reading location : points to first line of class constructor

Tags: c++

OK, so I had this model that was working perfectly for a few days now and all of a sudden I get this error : access violation reading location.  Since it was running "fine" last night, I can only assume I've been fortunate and undefined behavior has been working in my "favor" since I've gotten this model "working."  Furthermore, the debugger points to the first line of my constructor for my LengthDistribution object.

Initially I was thinking that something had gone out of scope before it could get used, but I changed the scope of the LD object (I think) and still the error persists.  Here's most of my main().

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int h_maxlength;
    int h_mass;
    int h_pause=0;
    int h_showFutures=0;
    int h_showPathways=0;
    int h_aggModel=0;
    int h_runModel=0;
    int h_pathwayTrace=0;
    int h_showCurrent=0;
    int h_numberOfIterations=15;
    int h_debugMode = 0;
    int* initialConditions;
    int h_hostIterations = 1;

    int threads = 8;

    //LD object representing initial conditions of the Stochastic Model
    LengthDistribution* LD;

    //Array of stochastic models that holds the results of each model run.
    StochasticModel** resultHolder;

    std::cout << "Run model? (1 - Yes, 2 - Enumerate, 3 - Integer Partition, 4- Test Operator) ";
    std::cin >> h_runModel;
    if(h_runModel == 1)
    {

        std::cout << "Enter number of iterations: ";
        std::cin >> h_numberOfIterations;
        std::cout << "Which type of aggregation model? (0 - Generalized, 1 - Becker-Doring, 2 - Knowles/Chou): ";
        std::cin >> h_aggModel;
        std::cout << "Enter desired mass (M): " ;
        std::cin >> h_mass;
        std::cout << "Enter desired maxlength (N): ";
        std::cin >> h_maxlength;
        std::cout << "Enter how many models to run: ";
        std::cin >> h_hostIterations;
        std::cout << "Enter how many threads to run: ";
        std::cin >> threads;

        //Initialize result holding array.
        resultHolder = new StochasticModel* [h_hostIterations*threads];

        //Create initial distribution from initial mass and desired maxlength.
        temp_initialConditions = new int [h_maxlength];
        for(int i = 0; i < h_maxlength; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
                temp_initialConditions[i] = h_mass;
            else
                temp_initialConditions[i] = 0;
        }

        //Create LD object based on initial conditions.
        LD = new LengthDistribution(temp_initialConditions, h_maxlength, h_debugMode);
        srand(1);


        //Allocate a stochastic model and give it a LD object as initial conditions.
        resultHolder[0] = new StochasticModel(LD, h_numberOfIterations, h_showFutures, h_showPathways, h_pause, h_aggModel, h_pathwayTrace, h_showCurrent, h_debugMode);
        //StochasticModel* model = new StochasticModel(LD, h_numberOfIterations, h_showFutures, h_showPathways, h_pause, h_aggModel, h_pathwayTrace, h_showCurrent, h_debugMode);
    }
```

}

The appropriate constructor for the LD object that is triggering this error follows :

```
LengthDistribution::LengthDistribution(int* initialDistribution, int maxlength, int debug)
{
    m_maxlength = maxlength;
    m_debug = debug;
    m_nonZeroCount = 0;
    m_nonZerosIndicesCrop = new int[m_nonZeroCount]; 
    m_baseStateHolder = new int*[m_nonZeroCount];
    m_futureStateCount=0;
    m_aggStateCount=0;
    m_fragStateCount=0; 
    m_base=new int[maxlength];
    m_myFreeEnergy=0;
    m_r=0;
    m_s=0;
    m_q=0;
    m_stateOrigin=0;
    m_partitionFunction=1; 
    m_futureLDHolder= new LengthDistribution*[m_nonZeroCount];
    m_futureStateHolder=new int*[m_nonZeroCount];
    m_myTransitProb = 0;
    m_lengthDistribution = new int[m_maxlength];
    memcpy(m_lengthDistribution, initialDistribution, m_maxlength*sizeof(int));
    m_lengthDistributionDouble = new double[m_maxlength];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_maxlength; i++)
        m_lengthDistributionDouble[i] = (double) m_lengthDistribution[i];
    m_mass = h_calcMass(m_lengthDistribution, maxlength);
    int* temp_lengthDistribution = new int[m_mass];
    for(int i = 0; i < m_mass; i++)
    {
        if(i < maxlength)
            temp_lengthDistribution[i] = m_lengthDistribution[i];
        else
            temp_lengthDistribution[i] = 0;
    }
    //m_lengthDistribution = temp_lengthDistribution;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxlength; i++)
    {
        m_base[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m_nonZeroCount; i++)
    {
        m_nonZerosIndicesCrop[i] = 0;
        m_baseStateHolder[i] = 0;
        m_aggStateHolder[i] = 0;
        m_fragStateHolder[i] = 0;
        m_futureStateHolder[i] = 0;
        m_aggLDHolder[i] = 0;
        m_fragLDHolder[i] = 0;
        m_futureLDHolder[i] = 0;
    }

    m_mlThreads = 8;
    if ( (maxlength % m_mlThreads) ==0 )
        m_mlBlocks = maxlength/m_mlThreads;
    else
        m_mlBlocks = maxlength/m_mlThreads+1;


    m_transitProb = new double[m_futureStateCount];
    m_transitRanges = new double[m_futureStateCount]; 

    h_calcFreeEnergy();
}
```

I'd really appreciate some ideas and suggestions.  Self-taught C++ has been fraught with distress.

Comment: Teach yourself to stop using `new` and double pointers until you're close to being an expert.

Comment: I doubt all this code is necessary to reproduce the problem. Try to remove bits until the problem disappears; you might even find it yourself when you realise what was the last thing you removed. Anyway, the code looks rather disorganised and C-ish to me; you might want to read a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).